# Download HTML from Gmail in Python

Tags: python, parsing, email, gmail, imap

I am attempting to download all emails from a certain sender in my gmail for analysis.  I am running into an error on line 23.

Here is my code:

```
import imaplib
import email

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')


username = raw_input('USERNAME (email):')
password = raw_input('PASSWORD: ')


try:
    mail.login(username, password)
    print "Logged in as %r !" % username
except imaplib.IMAP4.error:
    print "Log in failed."

mail.list()
# Out: list of "folders" aka labels in gmail.
mail.select("inbox") # connect to inbox.

fromWho = raw_input('FROM:')

result, data = mail.uid('search', None, '(FROM fromWho )') # search and return uids instead
latest_email_uid = data[0].split()[-1]
result, data = mail.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
raw_email = data[0][1]
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 23, in <module>
```

Any thoughts??

Comment: it says i can't upvote?

Comment: It may be that you didn't have enough reputation. Welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IMAP4.uid works as command method, just using UIDs. The first part must be a command, that you have as search. Hence, the other parameters should be as the ones in the search method, just remember to quoute the names in the command string.

You should try something like

> IMAP4.uid('SEARCH', None, '(FROM "{}")'.format(fromWho))

Comment: changing the formatting of the FROM worked.  i did not use the format(fromWho) and it still worked

Comment: i got rid of the varialbe and just put in the actual email.  this is what worked : "(FROM 'tiffany@e.tiffany.com')"

Comment: that way you cannot change the email easily. That should be 100% equivalent to using the format(fromWho).